# Change the name of a button in the parent component after clicking on a button inside modal (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter

I am working on an Angular 7 project and I want to change the name of a button from the parent component after clicking on a button from within the child component, which is a modal.

Currently, when I click on "Button A" from the parent, the modal opens. After that, when I click on "Button B" from within the modal, I want "Button A" from the parent to change its name to "C", for instance. I have tried using localStorage but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas on how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a shared service and observables? A few ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to communicate from Child to Parent component is via Event Emitters, first you define the event output in your child component like so :

```
@Output() clickedButton = new EventEmitter<Observable<any>>();
```

and next when hit the button the method that implements that button action should emit the event like so

```
this.clickedButton.emit(/* here goes any data you wanna pass to the parent component if its the case otherwise can be empty*/);
```

next on the parent component template just add (clickedButton)="your function to change the button text" like so :

```
<child-component (clickedButton)="changeButtonText($event)"></child-component>
```

and in your parent component you can change the button text to another text as you like, as long as the button text is a variable or you can access the button component and change the text but that sounds more complex than you need it to be

```
changeButtonText($event:any){
this.buttonTextVariable = 'C'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have an error: Failed to compile.

./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js. Do you know why?

Comment: No I don't, unfortunately never used that library saucelabs